# "New York" region appears more frequently than expected

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I'm running Firebase Analytics in a native Android/iOS app (linked to BigQuery).  I'm attempting to find the number of distinct users in each region (US state) over a certain time period. New York appears at the top of the list (substantially higher than expected) and doesn't match historical app usage.  With the exception of New York, other states appear in expected order.
Here's the query I'm using: (Edited to reflect the simplified query suggested by @Sergiiko)

```
SELECT 
  geo.region                     AS Region, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS TotalUsers
FROM `{table-name-here}.events_*` e1
WHERE (_TABLE_SUFFIX between '20200101' AND '20200128') 
GROUP BY Region
ORDER BY TotalUsers DESC
```

Is there something behind the scenes in BigQuery/Firebase that could explain why the "New York" region would appear more frequently than expected or is my query incorrect?

Comment: Could you provide some dummy data? So It is easier to investigate further.

Comment: How big are these numbers? Like, you should be able to actually verify for a sample of the user_pseudo_id if they're actually from NY? Also see if the same user id shows up for many regions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand, why do you need nested SELECT...

It seems that query might be simplified to

```
SELECT 
  geo.region                     AS Region, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS TotalUsers
FROM `{dataset-name}.events_*`
WHERE (_TABLE_SUFFIX between '20200101' AND '20200128') 
GROUP BY Region
ORDER BY TotalUsers DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  This does simplify the query, but the results are the same with New York events appearing far more than they should.